# Java Class wont notice numbers over 9

Tags: java, int

I need this Ten Green Bottles class to start at 10 and go down to 0. But it only starts at 9, I can't seem to get it to begin with 10. I imagine it has something to do with the "int bott_num = 9". Setting it to 8,7,6... works fine! Anything over 9 though and it believes its 9 anyway. Please help

```
import java.lang.*;

public class TenGreenBottles
{
    /**
     * This is the main entry point for the application
     */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int bott_num = 9;
        while (bott_num > 2){
            System.out.println(bott_num + " green bottles, hanging on the wall,");
            System.out.println(bott_num + " green bottles, hanging on the wall,");
            System.out.println("and if one green bottle, should accidentally fall,");
            System.out.println("there'll be " + (bott_num - 1) + " green bottles, hanging on the wall");
            System.out.println(" ");

            bott_num = bott_num - 1;
        }

        while  (bott_num > 1){
            System.out.println(bott_num + " green bottles, hanging on the wall,");
            System.out.println(bott_num + " green bottles, hanging on the wall,");
            System.out.println("and if one green bottle, should accidentally fall,");
            System.out.println("there'll be " + (bott_num - 1) + " green bottle, hanging on the wall");
            System.out.println(" ");

            bott_num = bott_num - 1;
        }

        System.out.println(bott_num + " green bottle, hanging on the wall,");
        System.out.println(bott_num + " green bottle, hanging on the wall,");
        System.out.println("and if that green bottle, should accidentally fall,");
        System.out.println("there'll be no green bottles, hanging on the wall");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("THE END");
    }

}
```

Comment: Um, nope. Set it to 15, and it starts with 15, then does 14, then 13 etc. I've tried it, and it behaved entirely as expected. As an aside, you never need to import `java.lang.*` - it's imported automatically. And now would be a good time to get into the habit of indenting your code more conventionally.

Comment: Set "int bott_num = " to 15? It still starts with 9 bottles...

Comment: Did you compile it (`javac ...`) after you changed it to 15?

Comment: Yup. Clicked compile, and then void main (string)... then it still starts with "9 green bottles...". I could set it to 100 and it'll still start with 9

Comment: @Pyrexo: Well, it's not clear what environment you're using, but I just copied your code, changed the starting number, compiled, and ran - and it was fine. I suggest you try changing other aspects of your code, and see whether you *still* see no difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined bott_num as

```
int bott_num = 9;
```

So it will start with 9 but your print:

```
System.out.println("there'll be " + (bott_num - 1) + " green bottles, hanging on the wall");
```

prints `bott_num - 1` which in your case would be 8. So i would sugges you start with 11 so you will get output like:

```
 11 green bottles, hanging on the wall,
 ..
 there'll be 10 green bottles, hanging on the wall
```

While if you want consistent result, then you could initialize it to 10 and change your print statement to:

```
System.out.println("there'll be " + bott_num + " green bottles, hanging on the wall");
```

Also your second while loop, is going to execute just once instead of starting say from 10 as you are decrementing `bott_num` in your while loop 1, so may be you could have temp variable that's assigned same value as `bott_num` and you decrement that variable rather than `bott_num` itself.

Comment: When I change    int bott_num = 9; to int bott_num = 11; it still comes out as 9... Is this happening  when you try the class too?

Comment: where do you see 9? Can you paste the output?

Comment: Once I chance the int bott num = 9 to int bott_num = 11 , I compile and then void main (string)... then it starts with "9 green bottles..."  when it should start with 10.

Comment: can you paste whatever output you see in your question please. Scroll up and you should see it starts with 11.

Comment: The output? you mean what comes up when I click void main string? 
This comes up: 

9 green bottles, hanging on the wall,
9 green bottles, hanging on the wall,
and if one green bottle, should accidentally fall,
there'll be 8 green bottles, hanging on the wall
 etc to 0